# JQuery click functions attached to each list item

Tags: jquery

I want three   < li >  appended in the aside area of the body of the HTML  document

Hey1

Hey2

Hey3

and to each of them  attached  a click toggle function so that it can show and hide
an appropriate div in the body of the  HTML.

```
   </aside>
  <div id="id1" > I am the  one </div>
  <div id="id2" > I am the  second</div>
  <div id="id3" > I am the  third</div>
  </body>
```

For example the   < li > Hey1  attached click function will ONLY toggle  the div with the id="id1"
and so on

the code  I have written is

```
   $(document).ready(function() {   $("div").hide();    
   jQuery.each([1,2,3], function(n,value){ n++; 

    $('aside').append("<li> hey"+value+" </li>").click(function(){$('#id'+value).toggle()});
    });
    })
```

Now the code creates the  < li > 's all right and it attaches to them the click function.
The problem is that  whichever of the  < li > I click 
all three of the < div > s toggle
when   what i  specifically want 
is that when , say 
the < li > Hey1   is clicked  THEN   ONLY  the area with the 
 < div id="id1" > I am the  one < /div>
 will be shown  and hidden.

I am thankful to any help

Answer (score 1):

You're not attaching the click handler to the `li`'s, but to the `aside`, do :

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $("div").hide();    
    $.each([1,2,3], function(n,value){
      $('<li />', {text: 'hey'+value}).appendTo('aside').on('click', function() {
          $('#id'+value).toggle();
      });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

that's because you attach click event to the aside, not li

```
$(document).ready(function() {   $("div").hide();    
    $.each([1,2,3], function(n,value){
        n++; 
        $li = $("<li> hey"+value+" </li>").click(function(){
            $('#id'+value).toggle();
        });
        $('aside').append($li);
    });
})
```